# Strip the extension from a file

Tags: php

I have a code that is working as i want it to apart from 1 problem.

You can see the result here http://test.whatanswered.com/health/what-can-a-first-aider-do.php on the right below "Related Articles" showing dead links.

The following is the HTML that should be displayed.

```
<p><a href="../health/name-of-the-page.php">Name of the page</a></p>
```

I would like to strip the dashes and php as above "Name of the page" but it also strips the dashes and php from the url.

The code is:

```
<?php 

if ($handle = opendir('health')) {
    $fileTab = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $fileTab[$file] = strtr(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME), '-', ' '); 
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    shuffle($fileTab);
    foreach(array_slice($fileTab, 0, 10) as $file => $health) {
        $thelist .= '<p><a href="../health/'.$file.'">'.$health.'</a></p>';
    }
}
?>
<?=$thelist?>
```

Comment: pathinfo($myFile,PATHINFO_FILENAME), and str_replace().... reading the manual helps

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand what you are asking. Can you try phrasing this question in a more clear way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've refactored your code a little - the `$fileTab` array now just stores filenames and converting this to a title happens at the point of display:

```
if ($handle = opendir('health')) {
    $fileTab = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $fileTab[] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    shuffle($fileTab);

    foreach(array_slice($fileTab, 0, 10) as $file) {
        $title = str_replace('-', ' ', pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME));
        $thelist .= '<p><a href="../health/'.$file.'">'.$title.'</a></p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but still no luck: [link]http://test.whatanswered.com/health/what-can-a-first-aider-do.php

Comment: I've rewritten my answer - please try again

Comment: Great that works a treat apart from i had to remove  => $health because it seemed to display a list of numbers. many thanks